# Different model for GET All, GET Id and POST in WebApi

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

My controllers require a different model for GET All, GET and POST, though they are technically the same resource. Is there a way I can use a single model to achieve this? Is it also common for this to occur in REST Based API's?

Comment: GET All and GET can't be the same resource.  You could implement them in the same controller.  Different URL, most likely a different resource.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. A resource is represented by a url and the actions you perform against it. E.g. api/cars/{id} - is what you would call a "cars" resource and you typically perform CRUD actions against it. Ideally your "Car" model should NOT change regardless of what action you perform against it.